# Angular 2 - Auto Close Modal After 5 Seconds

Tags: javascript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a form modal which on submission, then changes the form to some success wording.

What i'm after is when the success wording is displayed for the modal to automatically close (even fade out for fanciness) but i dont know how to do it.

Code is below

**Modal HTML (Skeleton)**

```
<form>
    <md-toolbar>
        <div>Section Header</div>
        <span style="flex: auto;"></span>
        <button *ngIf="initial" md-icon-button (click)="functionCall()">
            <md-icon>save</md-icon>
        </button>
        <button md-icon-button md-dialog-close>
            <md-icon>close</md-icon>
        </button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
        <md-input-container [hidden]="!initial">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Enter text" [(ngModel)]="fieldModel">
        </md-input-container>
        <p [hidden]="initial">Success.</p>
    </md-dialog-content>
</form>
```

**Modal Component (Skeleton)**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    fieldModel: string;
    initial = true;

    constructor() {}
    functionCall() {
        this.serviceCall.serviceName(this.fieldModel)
            .subscribe(data => {
                //On Success
                this.initial = false;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is leverage the RxJS methods:

```
this.serviceCall.serviceName(this.fieldModel)
  .do(() => this.initial = false)
  .delay(5000)
  .subscribe(() => this.initial = true);
```

This will set the `initial` flag to `false` after the service call completes, [wait five seconds](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html), then set it back to `true`.

If you want to have fade in-out, a simple option would be to use CSS classes to set opacity with a transition. Alternatively, look into Angular's built-in animation support.